# Retrofit 2. How to handle error JSON inside response, if code is 200

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android, gson

I am using Vk Api, and during 1 scenario I am getting a response object with code 200, but body of it's an Error JSON.

I want to ask you - is it possible to somehow get the error object from response and look at the `error_code` that has been returned from the Vk Api.

I am using `Retrofit 2` on android and `GsonConverterFactory`.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
class NetworkCheckerInterceptor(val networkChecker: NetworkChecker) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        if (!networkChecker.isConnected()) {
            throw NoNetworkConnectionException("No network connection.")
        }
        try {
            val response =  chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
            val error = Gson().fromJson(response.body()?.string(), Error::class.java)
            return response
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            throw SocketTimeoutException()
        } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
            throw UnknownHostException()
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error when I am trying to get 'Error' object.

Json error example:

```
  {
  "error": {
    "error_code": 7,
    "error_msg": "Permission to perform this action is denied",
    "request_params": [
      {
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "stats.get"
      },
      {
        "key": "timestamp_to",
        "value": "1542549195"
      },
      {
        "key": "month",
        "value": "month"
      },
      {
        "key": "group_id",
        "value": "56461699"
      },
      {
        "key": "v",
        "value": "5.87"
      },
      {
        "key": "interval",
        "value": "month"
      },
      {
        "key": "stats_groups",
        "value": "visitors"
      },
      {
        "key": "timestamp_from",
        "value": "1514757660"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The only thing I care about is `"error_code": 7` it's about permition problem.

So, how can I get this object even if my response code is 200 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create base class for VK network response

```
abstract class BaseVkResponse<T> {
    var response: T? = null
    var error: VKError? = null // (from vk sdk)
}
```

and each response should extend it. For example

```
class NewsItem {
    var type: String? = null
    var text: String? = null
    var date: Long? = null
}

class NewsPage {
    var items: List<NewsItem>? = null
    @SerializedName("nextFrom")
    var nextFrom: String? = null
}

class NewsResponse : BaseVkResponse<NewsPage>()
```

and retrofit interface looks like

```
interface VkService {
    @GET("newsfeed.getRecommended")
    fun getNews(@Query("access_token") accessToken: String,
                @Query("v") apiVersion: String,
                @Query("count") count: Int?,
                @Query("start_from") startFrom: String?): Single<NewsResponse>
}
```

Then register special type adapter to parse VkError type

```
internal class ErrorTypeAdapter : JsonDeserializer<VKError> {

    @Throws(JsonParseException::class)
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement,
                             typeOfT: Type,
                             context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): VKError? {
        return try {
            VKError(JSONObject(json.toString()))
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            null
        }
    }
}

val gson = GsonBuilder().apply {
    registerTypeAdapter(VKError::class.java, ErrorTypeAdapter())
}
```

If response's `error` field is not null, you should handle it as you wish. In other cases you can treat it as successful.